# How to close (auto hide) WPF window after 10 sec using timer

Tags: c#, wpf

How to close (auto hide) WPF window after 10 sec using a timer in C#?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
private void StartCloseTimer()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d);
    timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Tick -= TimerTick;
    Close();
}
```